# Twitter Framework iOS - After login success

Tags: ios5, twitter

If I show the user a popup that has the "Settings" button, they click it and go to the OS settings page and enter their Twitter Credentials, then they go back into my game and enter the foreground.

How will I know that the user had just logged in their twitter account and that I need to an oauth request for their tokens?

An edge case would be - The user was on my twitter page and left the game for a text message, then enters my game. I have a foreground function that is invoked, but I do not want to assume they logged into twitter if they didn't.

Shouldn't the Twitter Framework handle this for us?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by your use of "Twitter Framework iOS" you mean iOS 5's Twitter framework, you can set a BOOL to YES when the user attempts to send a tweet initially, and return it to NO if the are successful. That gives you the ability to check for this bool, as well as whether the composer `canSendTweet` in `viewDidAppear` to determine how you should handle your oauth request.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet] && myBOOL) {
        //send oauth request
        myBool = NO;
    }
}
```